# Convert HTML form into Angular POST request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wordpress, post

I have this form in HTML and I am trying to convert it into a POST request using a frontend framework (either AngularJS or Angular2).  The purpose of this form is to allow a client to subscribe to my wordpress blog.  I am trying to convert it from PHP to Angular2 (if someone knows how to convert it to AngularJS I can convert to Angular2 from there).  How would I do this?  What would have to be in the body of the POST request vs query strings?  I am having trouble understanding exactly what role each part of this form plays in the POST request.

**EDIT:**  Just to clarify, I know how to use AngularJS and Angular2 and how to use the HTTP service in both of them.  I am wondering how to convert the form into the body/query strings of the request.

```
<form action="/blog/" class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" id="subscribe-blog">

    <!-- add hidden inputs for wordpress jetpack widget -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe" />
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sub-type" value="widget" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_fragment" value="blog_subscription-2" />

    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control wide" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Enter email address">
    <button type="submit" name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget" class="btn btn-submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Would something along the lines of this be correct?

```
postForm() {
    var body = {
        action: 'subscribe',
        source: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/',
        sub-type: 'widget',
        redirect_fragment: 'blog_subscription-2',
        email: 'clientEmailAddress@gmail.com',  // don't think this is right
        // not sure what to do with `jetpack_subscriptions_widget` attribute on the submit button either
    };
    return this.http.post(`http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/`, body)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            return data;
        });
}
```

Comment: Do you have experience with Angular (either 1 or 2) ? What do you mean with "*I am trying to convert it from PHP to Angular2*"? I understand you are doing a request with this form to a php (controller or whatever handles the request in the backend). Is that so?

Comment: I have strong experience with both and know how to make POST requests with both.  I am wondering how to format the request with all of the data that it needs from the form.

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). The inputs need `ng-model` directives. The form needs a `ng-submit` directive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `angular.min.js` and script.js

**html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" ng-click="send(name)"/>

</body>
```

**angular js code:**
script.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', funtion($scope, $http){
     $scope.name = "";   // intially the input field is empty. As you type in the input field, the value will be updated here.
     $scope.send = function(name){
           alert(name);
           var url = $scope.name;  // try to enter an url
           $http.get(url).then(function Success(res){
               // here you can do anything with res
           }, function Error(err){
              alert(error);
           })
     }

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using angular, you split the application in parts:

- view (*html*)
- process some validations, etc (*controller*)
- and do some model logic processing (*service*).

If you want to make the http request completely with angular to an *endpoint* (backend service, *REST*, or any other), usually in this case:

- You use `ng-model` for each input field you need to send in the request, something like `<input type="text" ng-model="val">`. In your case your html would be something like:

**html**

```
<form ng-submit="send()" class="form-inline" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" id="subscribe-blog">

 <!--no need of 'action' attribute in the form since the post will be done using angular-->

    <!-- add hidden inputs for wordpress jetpack widget -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe" ng-model="subscribe"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/" ng-model="source"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sub-type" value="widget" ng-model="widget" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_fragment" value="blog_subscription-2" ng-model="redirect_fragment"/>

    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control wide" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Enter email address" ng-model="email">
    <button type="submit" name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget" class="btn btn-submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Then in your controller you can *process* all your *ng-model* if needed and then pass those values to a (angular) service like this

```
//....angular controller
function send(){
    //..collect params using the ng-models
    var params = [];
    params['email'] = $scope.email; //here you define 'email' as the name of the param received by the webservice as input !!!
    myService.sendValues(params).then(function(data){
    })
 }
```

...where you would finally send the values to the php service like code below:

```
//... angular service

function sendValues(params){
    var url = "miendpointurl/subscribe";
    //... at this pont in params you have all those params you named like 'email', 'subscribe' and so on
    return $http.post(url, params).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    },
    function(responseOnError){
        return responseOnError.data;
    }
}
```

Angular will interact with the php service transparently to you and will give you back the server response.